# How can I implement this algorithm to find all pairs of points at a distance of 1?

Tags: computational-geometry

I am trying to find an algorithm which, given a set of N points on a 2D plane, can find all pairs of points at a distance of exactly 1. [I believe this is similar to this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/148481/given-a-vector-of-points-what-is-the-fastest-algorithm-to-find-all-pairs-of-poi). I looked at the answers to the linked question.

One answer mentions a "Well Separated Points Decomposition", although I am unsure of how to use it to enumerate all the pairs of points in the answer.

Another answer mentions the "incidence reporting problem", but I am unable to fill in the details of the algorithm that is described.

Can someone please explain how either of those two algorithms works?

Answer (score 1):

It very much depends on your data. Say you have two million points, with $x_i$ randomly in the interval [0, 1000000]. Simple and fast: Sort the points by first coordinate, then for every point $(x_i, y_i)$ you compare with the points $(x_j, y_j)$ for j ranging from i + 1 to n as long as $x_j ≤ x_i + 1$. On average you compare with two other points.

Now assume you have two million points, with coordinates randomly in the interval [0, 2]. The algorithm above is totally useless. Divide the x-axis into intervals of size d for a suitable d, say 0.01, then for each of these intervals you collect all points with $x_i$ in the interval, and sort them by $y_i$.

For example, you will have all points with $0.37 ≤ x_i ≤ 0.38$. You compare them to points with $x_j$ in the intervals from $[0.00, 0.01]$ to $[1.37, 1.38]$. For each $x_i$ and each interval you compare with, you calculate two ranges where $y_j$ might be ($(x_j, y_j)$ is somewhere on the circle around $(x_i, y_i)$ with radius 1). Since the points are sorted by $y_j$ you can access all these points quickly.

You compare each $(x_i, y_i)$ with points within a total area of about $2\cdot \pi \cdot d)$, so the smaller d is, the more area you save, but the overhead grows.